# Fetching all Tweets NameError: name 'tweet' is not defined tweepy twitter API

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

My Code worked for 450 tweets, but I cant fetch older tweets than the last 450.
The oldest ID I can fetch is : 1355068728128516101
Anybody has an Idea why ?

````
tweet_liste =[]


i = 1
while i != 0:
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,max_id = maxid,count=200, screen_name=screenname, include_rts=False, exclude_replies=True, tweet_mode='extended').items():
        if str((tweet.id))+";" +str(tweet.created_at)+";"+ str(tweet.full_text)+"\n" not in tweet_liste:
            tweet_liste.append(str((tweet.id))+";" +str(tweet.created_at)+";"+ str(tweet.full_text)+"\n")
    print(len(tweet_liste))
    maxid = tweet.id```
````

Comment: The timelines API provides access to the most recent 3200 Tweets from a user. You’ve chosen to exclude Retweets and replies from the results, but if they were included, maybe there would be 3200 Tweets in the timeline (i.e. 450+replies+retweets). If that is the case, you will not be able to retrieve any more Tweets, and would need to use a full archive search - available in the v2 API with Academic Research access - to get any more Tweets by the user.

Comment: @andy thank you very much !
I couldnt find this information in the twitter docu. could you provide me your source ?